# Ionic navigation cannot load a page

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic, and I'm trying to create a `ion-nav-view` as shown in the tutorial [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/).
I have created 2 pages and set an angular conf file. While loading I get the following error in my browser: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/ITAI/Development/Ionic/LaughWithMe/www/templates/register.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])


.config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
// Set and define states
$stateProvider
    .state('register', {
        url: '/register',
        templateUrl: 'templates/register.html'
    });
})
```

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

    <ion-nav-bar></ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right">
    </ion-nav-view>

<!--    <script id="index" type="text/ng-template">
  <!-- The title of the ion-view will be shown on the navbar -->
  <ion-view title="'Home'">
    <ion-content>
      <!-- The content of the page -->
      <a ui-sref="register">Register</a>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>-->

    </body>

</html>
```

register.html:

```
<h1> hello world!</h1>
```

I have a bit of experience with angular, but I got very confused this framework. I can't tell where is the directives and how to inject them into my HTML pages.
What I tried to do is to link the `register` page to the `index.html` page. The simplest way there is.

Answer (score 0):

A cors error usually indicates that you are running the project without using an http serve.
Try running

```
ionic serve 
or 
phonegap serve
```

from the root of your project.